# Kubenet response time degraded, solved using hostNetwork: true, with unicorn app

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I’m trying to debug an issue that is solved by using `hostNetwork: true`. The k8s installation is using kubenet, and the k8s version is 1.9.8.

The installation is done with kops on AWS, using m4.xlarge and c4.xlarge instances.

The problem is the following:

When we migrated this application to kubernetes, the response time (percentile 95) for a certain endpoint increased about 20-30%.

This issue is solved, though, when using `hostNetwork: true` in the yaml. The performance is the same than it was on VMs for this endpoint, i.e the percentile 95 for the response time is the same for this endpoint.

I’ve asked this in the kubernetes office hours on July 18th (yeah, a while ago!) and the `hostNetwork: true` workaround come up there.

Please note that all kube-proxy stuff can be discarded as this increased response time is seen when measuring in the app itself. I mean, the ruby app measures the time it takes and send it to the log collector. This time, that is since the request is started to be processed by the app till it finished, shows the degraded performance already. So kube-proxy and that stuff is out of the equation.

The pod has 3 containers:

- Nginx
- A log collector
- The app (a ruby app running with unicorn)

These apps are also in the VMs mode

What I tried:

- Found a way to reproduce using ab(apache benchmark)

  - `ab -c 1 -n 1000 'https://...`
  - The same happens with http, instead of https
- I tried removing the nginx container, but it doesn’t change anything.
  The log collector is used over localhost, and the very same thing is done on the VMs that do not exhibit the problem
- I tried using unix sockets between nginx and the app, instead of localhost, but it didn’t change anything either.
- Tried using same instances (m4.xlarge) with EKS: the same happens. Although the performance cost of not using `hostNetwork: true` is less, about 10%. Please note that EKS does not use kubenet and uses their own network overlay based on some open source.
- Tried using another endpoint that just returns a string (puts “Ok”) and the issue does not happen
- Tried using an endpoint that returns a few MBs (like `"Die" * 10 * 1024 * 1024`), and the issue does not happen either
- Tried the same endpoint that has the issue with different query string params, so the response is big (9MB) or short (130kb) and both reliably reproduce the issue
- Tried a nodejs application, that returns similar jsons from similar sources, and the issue is not present (nor with short/long responses)
  What might do next:

So, I’m trying to debug this issue to understand what it is and, hopefully, stop using `hostNetwork: true`. There seems to path to dig further:

- Try other CNIs (EKS showed less performance degradation) to see if the performance changes
- See what this endpoint does or how it interacts with unicorn and the whole stack. One big difference is that unicorn is one process per request (synchronous) and nodejs is not.
- Try to use more newer machines (m5/c5) to see if they mitigate the performance hit. But, as this issue is not present with the current instances using them as VMs, seems that if it helps, will only hide the problem

This endpoint that has the perf problem, is an endpoint in ruby that reads a database and gets returns a json. The database, the host, the network, all seem fine (monitoring CPU, disk IO, swap, etc. with vmstat, our regular tools, AWS console, checking kern.log, sysloca and that stuff also)

By any chance, did you have a similar experience? Or do you have any other ideas on how to continue to debug this issue?

Any ideas or any kind of help is more than welcome!

Rodrigo

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/56903

The workarounds mentioned there (like `dnsPolicy: Default`) solve the issue for me.

These two post explain the problem in detail: https://www.weave.works/blog/racy-conntrack-and-dns-lookup-timeouts and https://blog.quentin-machu.fr/2018/06/24/5-15s-dns-lookups-on-kubernetes/

And also provide some workarounds.

long story short: there is a race condition in nf that affects connection-less protocols (like UDP) when doing DNAT/SNAT. The weave guys have sent a patch to fix most of the races. To work-around you can either use an external dns (i.e. not kube-dns as it is exposed via a service and, so, uses DNAT), set flags for glibc (but don't work for musl), use a minimal delay with `tc`, etc.

Note: Using `dnsPolicy: Default` does the trick because it is using an external DNS server (i.e. not hosted in kubernetes and accessed via a service, that does DNAT).

I'll test the glibc flags for my cluster, although the `dnsPolicy: Default` thing does solve the issue for me, as we are using k8s DNS service resolution on some apps.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the overhead you're experiencing is due to Docker's NAT.
`hostNetwork: true` exposes the host's network to the pod/container(s), as opposed to using a NAT, providing better performance... But reducing security.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, that is not the only thing that changes. Kubenet, or any other CNI, is avoided also. Why do you think it's NAT? Do you have any suggestion to try to confirm that is the issue?

As I said, it doesn't seem to happen on other apps. And they have the same RPMs and that stuff. I can monitor the iptables counters, but not sure that is it.

Do you have any idea on how to confirm is NAT or not?

Comment: I would agree with @samhain1138. But actually to confirm it we need some more details about your architecture, load balancing and how did you measure the latency - between which points?

Comment: It's a bit tricky to debug, and while I can probably guide you through it, I think I'd try to help you focus here:
You can't really use `hostNetwork: true` for security and reliability reasons.
Unfortunately you'll have to deal with the overhead of NAT, CNI, etc. So how do engineers get around such issues in Kubernetes? I'd suggest focusing on tweaking your HPA (HorizontalPodAutoscaler) to provide more resources (replicas...) when the PODs are choking on CPU/RAM (easy to monitor with Prometheus). Hope this helps!

Comment: @samhain1138 @aurelius I know the downsides, that's why I'm looking for another way to solve it. Sorry didn't clarified :)

It can't be solved by HPA, as each pod is taking more on the requests. It's not a matter of load (concurrency 1 in the `ab` test). Some requests  just take too much. In fact, for NAT to be a noticeable overhead seems REALLY weird.

Oh, I found the solution! it is a reported kubernetes [bug] https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/56903 and those workarounds solve the problem

Thanks a lot, guys!